# What happened to reputation change history?

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upcoming Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes)

Currently when I navigate to any user's profile, including my own the reputation section says "You have no reputation changes". I have read [We've moved heaven and earth to ensure your score is always correct!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes) but it does not mention when exactly the change going to happen on SO, neither it mentions any display irregularities similar to one I'm observing.

What's happening?

Comment: It's still being updated. There's a *lot* of information to go through. They literally like *just* pushed the update onto Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The change is happening right now.  The beginning of the post you linked says:

> During the rollout you will see empty reptuation tabs on profiles as we transition to the new storage behind the scenes, they'll be restored as the recalc rolls though each user.

Comment: People just can't read, can they? Sorry, and thank you for help.